# In Xamarin.Android is there a simple way to find a map location based on a search-term instead of LatLng?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In iOS maps there is a clear illustration in the guides on how to search the map using a search term:

```
public void Search (string forSearchString)
{
    // create search request
    var searchRequest = new MKLocalSearchRequest ();
    searchRequest.NaturalLanguageQuery = forSearchString;
    searchRequest.Region = new MKCoordinateRegion (map.UserLocation.Coordinate, new MKCoordinateSpan (0.25, 0.25));

    // perform search
    var localSearch = new MKLocalSearch (searchRequest);

    localSearch.Start (delegate (MKLocalSearchResponse response, NSError error) {
        if (response != null && error == null) {
            this.MapItems = response.MapItems.ToList ();
            this.TableView.ReloadData ();
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("local search error: {0}", error);
        }
    });
}
```

However every android example I've seen is instead using coordinates.

Is there a simple equivalent for using a search-term for Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's `Places` API.

Note: You ***are*** using a lat/long in your example to define the the search region.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
    .Builder(this)
        .AddApi(PlacesClass.GEO_DATA_API)
        .AddApi(PlacesClass.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
        .AddApi(LocationServices.API)
        .EnableAutoManage(this, this)
        .Build();
mGoogleApiClient.BlockingConnect();
var searchText = "Starbucks Coffee";
var latLngBuilder = LatLngBounds.InvokeBuilder();
var currentLocation = new LatLng(47.60357, -122.3295); // use Seattle, WA as default if Fused location returns null
var mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.GetLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
if (mLastLocation != null)
{
    currentLocation.Latitude = mLastLocation.Latitude;
    currentLocation.Longitude = mLastLocation.Longitude;
}
var zoomFactor = 0.005f; // ~ a few city block... adjust as needed...
latLngBuilder.Include(new LatLng(currentLocation.Latitude - zoomFactor, currentLocation.Longitude - zoomFactor));
latLngBuilder.Include(new LatLng(currentLocation.Latitude + zoomFactor, currentLocation.Longitude + zoomFactor));
var latLngBounds = latLngBuilder.Build();

var results = await PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetAutocompletePredictionsAsync(mGoogleApiClient, searchText, latLngBounds, null);
if (results.Status.IsSuccess)
{
    Log.Debug("SO", $"{results.Count} {searchText} results were found close to your location");
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        Log.Debug("SO", $"{item.PlaceId}");
    }
}
else
    Log.Error("SO", results.Status.StatusMessage);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Foursquare API to search a place by its name. The API will give you the coordinates.

https://developer.foursquare.com/

In Android you can give coordinates and get the adres list, but if you want the reverse method you should use an API that supports this like Foursquare's.